# php- how to get shell_exec() output from linux terminal while executing the command?

Tags: php, linux, shell-exec

i am running one linux command with `shell_exec()` in my php script.

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/linux-command ');
```

`After` execution of the command i am getting the value into a variable. That's okay.
But, here my linux command will give the output `continuously in terminal`.
It will come like this..

```
$linux-command  
123    456    789  
789    456    123  
123    456    789 .. //and so on..(by pressing 'Ctrl+c' only we can stop this.
```

For every 5 seconds it will display one line. how to retrieve the line for every 5 sec.
My Page is in loading  ........ Because, it is waiting for the `$output`.
Is there any way to solve my problem ??
Any idea is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791875/how-to-run-shell-script-with-live-feedback-from-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the passthru function. The output is displayed directly. You can test it with this small script:

```
<?php
passthru('tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log');
?>
```

Comment: hmm.. Why the page is in loading ???...... not showing anything .. @lexmihaylov
Any ways i don't want direct output into the webpage. i want the result in a **table**

Comment: sorry I thought the you were talking about a cli script not a web script.

Comment: Hmm. can you use shell_exec($command.' > '.$filename.' 2>'.$filename.' &'); and after that just periodicaly get with an ajax method the contents from $filename, parse it and do something with it ?

Comment: hey.. i m not dealing with files yaar.. it is the output of a command, which gives statistics of the system. ok ? @lexmihaylov

Answer (score 0):

You can use `popen`, check the manual for more details [popen manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php)